# indexing and substitution of xts elements

Tags: r, xts, matrix-indexing

I have these two object:

[sig (class matrix)](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/102669/sig.txt)
and

[xts (class xts)](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/102669/xts.txt)

In the first object I want to find the position where this condition is satisfied:
`"sig != mlag(sig) & sig != 0"`

When I have these positions I want to substitute value in the xts object (zero for example) in the same position where the condition in `sig` was satisfied

I need to understand the correct way to do these.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way. I'm not familiar with the `mlag` function, and you don't say where it comes from, so I'm just going to use `diff.xts`.

```
sigSubset <- diff.xts(sig) != 0 & sig != 0
sigSubset[1,] <- FALSE  # remove any NA
x[sigSubset] <- sig[sigSubset]
```

Comment: Why  if i type 
x[sigSubset]  get                                                                   Error in `[.xts`(xts, sigSubset) : 'i' or 'j' out of range  ?

Comment: @Fryc: I have no idea. This works for me using R-3.0.2 and the latest xts on CRAN.

Comment: it's very strange because if i type: x[sigSubset] <- sig[sigSubset] it works. But if i type only x[sigSubset] to see the results i receive the error

Comment: @Fryc: Sorry, I misunderstood. `x[sigSubset]` doesn't work because it doesn't make sense for a time-series structure. Try `sig[sigSubset]` and notice that it returns a vector. There's no time-series equivalent of that behavior.